# Sending object with Kafka / Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I just want to send my BackAccount object with producer, and I want to consume that object. I have Producer and Consumer Config, but it gives me error.

My KafkaProducerConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {


    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, BankAccount> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, BankAccount> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }



}
```

KafkaConsumerConfig :

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {


    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "json");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, BankAccount> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerConfigs(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(BankAccount.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, BankAccount> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, BankAccount> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

It is really basic but my controller is :

```
public class KafkaController {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String,BankAccount> kafkaTemplate;

    private static final String TOPIC = "my-topic";

    @GetMapping("/publish/{message}")
    public String postKafka(@PathVariable("message") final String message){
        BankAccount bankAccount= new BankAccount();
        bankAccount.setBalance(120.0);

        kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC,bankAccount);
        return "Succesfully";
    }


}
```

I have error in KafkaConsumerConfig :

```
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerConfigs(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(BankAccount.class));
```

in here : JsonDeserializer<>(BankAccount.class)
Diamond operator is not applicable for non-parametrized types

I did the same thing in reference link: https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-json-serializer-deserializer-example.html

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you show your imports

Comment: the problem with wrong import class as there are two classes `JsonDeserializer`:
`import org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer;`
`import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;`

Comment: also your consumer should have `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` 
as ` "127.0.0.1:9092"`

Comment: Yes ! I know the BOOTSTRAP config thanks and I have solved problem. I have changed the imports. Thank you very very much

Comment: please vote up the comments that helped you ;)

Comment: Yes but I have less than 15 reputations, I think I can not :(
Of course you are right, these comments are very valuable for me.